# How to print a Python dict containing byte strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pprint

I've got a dictionary with keys as byte strings and values as byte strings and would like to print a cleaned up version of it. Here is an example pair:

```
{b'cf1:c1': b'test-value'}
```

I've tried doing json.dumps, but I get an error saying that

```
TypeError: key b'cf1:c1' is not a string
```

I've also tried pprint. Are there any libraries or easy ways to do this?

Ideally the result would look like

```
{
    'cf1:c1': 'test-value'
}
```

Comment: Please explain little more
>>> {b'cf1:c1': b'test-value'}
{'cf1:c1': 'test-value'}
>>> a = {b'cf1:c1': b'test-value'}
>>> a
{'cf1:c1': 'test-value'}

Comment: `print({b'cf1:c1': b'test-value'})`? This works in python3

Comment: `json.dumps` doesn't work because python dictionaries are not JSON. You would need to first convert your dictionary to JSON first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new dictionary with decoded keys and values like so:

```
x = {b'cf1:c1': b'test-value'}
y = {k.decode("utf-8"):v.decode("utf-8") for k,v in x.items()}
```

Then you should be able to display `y` as you desire.

Comment: Doing this and then json.dumps(y, indent=4, sort_keys=True) gives me the result I was looking for. Thanks.